# Angular2 - cookie in request headers

Tags: http, angular

How to make Angular2 memorize all cookies from Response Headers and send it in Request Headers when i access to server!

Comment: The browser does that for you automatically.

Comment: But when i send request, there are no cookie in Request Headers

Comment: Then maybe the response doesn't set the cookie (show it). Or it tries setting cookies for another domain. Or the path of the cookies isn't right? Or you disabled cookies in your browser. Provide all the relevant details.

Comment: I have auth service and when i sign up, in Responce Headers there is Set-cookie with 'session_id', but when i want to get profile i send GET request,and in Request Headers there is no Cookie at all

Comment: Yes. That's understood. But if you don't provide any detail about the response, the way you set the cookie, where the response comes from, where the request goes to, what the cookie parameters are, we can't help.

Comment: This is my POST request headers where i have 'Set-Cookie'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 28 Feb 2017 10:18:44 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Set-Cookie:sessionid=gd3j9aovdlfgdjyje84y7eumwn6uxq7v; expires=Tue, 14-Mar-2017 10:18:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=MeAtSLDedV5mNocw4PRUZt5WpCOp0MtRHTSrYlaGfN6wYw6oX7hWK9fcHx9v380I; expires=Tue, 27-Feb-2018 10:18:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary:Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Comment: This is GET request headers where i haven't  Cookie Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:10.0.1.3:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: Post that in the question, properly formatted. It's unreadable this way. And tell where the response comes from (URL), and where the request goes to (URL)

Comment: Post request headers Set-Cookie:sessionid=gd3j9aovdlfgdjyje84y7eumwn6uxq7v; expires=Tue, 14-Mar-2017 10:18:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=MeAtSLDedV5mNocw4PRUZt5WpCOp0MtRHTSrYlaGfN6wYw6oX7hWK9fcHx9v380I; expires=Tue, 27-Feb-2018 10:18:44 GMT; Max-Age=31449

Comment: response comes from(http://10.0.1.3:8000/api/login/) and request goes to(http://10.0.1.3:8000/api/profile/)

Answer (score 2):

You should configure your request

`let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });`

Comment: does not work, cookies sent by previous request are not automaticaly populated in the next request header